# Loading webpage asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I have a WebApp in HTML5.

Here is the [link](http://teckzone.in/fbinstant/)

I wanted to load the whole webpage asynchronously. Like when the webpage is accessed I want to show the user a loading image and the page is loaded completely in async mode in the background. I tried to load the scripts async but it doesnt much affect its behavior.

Is there a way this is possible !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same method as Tobias Krogh suggested.

But rather than putting the contents in the #main by using plain old JS

```
document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

Use Jquery to put the contents in the body using .html()

```
$("body").html(request.responseText);
```

Edit: 
And load the CSS & JS using a JS loader.
Possible [Lazyload](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload) or [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/), to load them asynchronously.
That should do the Job !

Comment: Worked but still having issues with the scripts

Answer (score 2):

render an empty body that only has a loading image as background set... in the head you have a script tag that does an ajax call on dom ready and loads the desired content...

EDIT: the desired content of course should contain every other markup and script tag that is needed... then update the body with the response

```
document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

EDIT 2: I recommend to write that head script in native javascript as you only need less < 1kb to make a clean (even cross-browser ajax working) call to a defined url... in your ajax response you can be sure nothing will be overwritten or loaded twice (besides maybe the ajax functionality if you load a library)

Comment: I tried this one ! But the problem is that the content is getting displayed but the scripts arent running anymore on the page

Answer (score 0):

You could manage to do this by setting some kind of overlay with loader in your css which is visible ( at first ) and later after your page is fully loaded, remove the overlay ( fade it out ) with javascripting...

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/6Ldyd/

Of course you should make some kind of callback function to remove the overlay after the last element of your page is loaded ( or script to call it after the last element is loaded )

Comment: but this again has to load all the elements beforehand, so it would still be slow. Loading body via ajax is surely a better option.

Comment: If you place your css files at the top of your page (html file), and the scripts at the bottom of your page, your overlay div will be rendered as soon as the browser receives first KBs of the response data. So the user will see the loader on the overlay and wait for the rest of your scripts / html to load.